# In sequelize, how to define a relationship where X belongs to either A or B?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following hierarchy:

```
Moon belongs to Planet, Planet belongs to System.
System has many Planet, Planet has many Moon.
```

I want a model called 'Base', that can belong to either a Planet or a Moon. Both schemas have a 'hasOne' relationship to a Base.

How do I achieve this, in Sequelize?

Comment: This information is in the docs http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html

Comment: No, it documents how to add a plain 1:1 relationship, but there's nothing about how to add a relationship where the owner can be ONE of MULTIPLE types.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new model called base with nullable FKs to both models

```
const Base = sequelize.define('Base', {
  MoonId: { type: DataTypes.Integer, allowNull: true },
  PlanetId: { type: DataTypes.Integer, allowNull: true },
});

Base.associate = function (models) {
  File.belongsTo(models.Moon, {
    foreignKey: 'MoonId'
  });
  File.belongsTo(models.Planet, {
    foreignKey: 'PlanetId'
  });
}
```